# Get Int value from String

Tags: json, swift

I'm getting an api response like this:

```
{"id":10,"user_name":"test"}
```

I'm able to parse the user_name in a tableview without problems but the id always appears blank

This is my cellForRowAt func:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userDataCell", for: indexPath) as! UserDataCell
        let userDetails = responseArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.userNameField.text = userDetails["user_name"] as? String
        cell.idTextField.text = userDetails["id"] as? String
        return cell
    }
```

I guess the problem that I'm trying to parse a string when I'm getting Int

Modifiying to `as? Int`

```
cell.idTextField.text = userDetails["id"] as? Int
```

Didn't solve the problem. Any help?

Comment: `print(userDetails)` and make sure `id` actually has a value, `as? Int` should definitely work if the value is there and the correct key is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this as the temporary solution?

```
cell.idTextField.text = String(userDetails["id"] as? Int ?? 0)
```

Comment: Your default value is a string

Comment: it will be aloways 0

Comment: We need to cast a string to int **Int(string)** like this.
try this **String(Int(userDetails["id"] ?? 0))**

Answer (score 1):

you can make a safe convertion from string to int:

```
  if let myInt = Int(userDetails["id"] as? String ?? "") {

        }
```

update:

```
cell.idTextField.text = userDetails["id"] as? Int
```

Anyway when you set it to `idTextField` id must be of type String not Int, just change this: `cell.idTextField.text = userDetails["id"] as? String ?? ""`

if you want to set the id as `Int` you need to set like this:

```
 if let id = Int(userDetails["id"]) {
                cell.idTextField.text = "\(id)"
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two steps, first try to get an Int and then assign text field to get better control of what is assigned to the text field

```
if let intValue = dict["id"] as? Int {
    cell.idTextField.text = String(intValue)
} else {
    cell.idTextField.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cell.idTextField.text = userDetails["id"] as? String ?? userDetails["id"] as? Int ?? "none"
```

Comment: Your default value is a string